# double d = 1000 / 3600; result in to a 0?

Tags: java, double, divide

I doing a simple calculation from 2 variable and I got in to an issue...
In fact when I try to do " double d = 1000 (which is the first var) / 3600 (which is the 2nd var); it result in a 0. So why ? Any hint about that ?

Comment: 1000 and 3600 are integers, not doubles.

Comment: `1000` and `3600` are both int's, even though `d` is a `double`. Change it to `1000.0/3600.0`

Comment: Thanks for you comments ^^

Comment: double d = (double) 1000 / (double) 3600; // d = 0.2777777777777778

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1000 and 3600 are ints, so when you do 1000 / 3600 you get 0. Then, you are assigning double d to this result of zero. You can instead write 1000.0/3600.0 or if these two numbers are variables, you can cast them to doubles first.

Comment: So I could do this ? double d = (double) a / (double) b; ?

Comment: @ZeTioZ, you could do that ...  but it is sufficient to convert only one number to a double and it will still work

Comment: Thanks for your help ^^ I figured it out with your solution :)

PS: How I make this question "resolved" ?